# How to "round" GeoJSON coordinates using mapbox

Tags: android, ios, mapbox, geojson, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am developing a react-native-mapbox-gl app on Windows 10. I need to "round" GeoJSON points uploaded to the app so that they appear in the center of a house block. For example:

Figure 1: A marker is added on the northeaster corner of a block
[image: Figure 1: A marker is added on the northeaster corner of a block]

Figure 2: The marker is "rounded" / "moved" to the geographical center of the block
[image: Figure 2: The marker is "rounded" / "moved" to the geographical center of the block]

Since it's unfeasible to manually create a GeoJSON geometry for every street there is, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encode the boundaries of a particular block as a `Polygon` feature, you can then use Turf.js's [`centroid` method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) to calculate the center of said polygon. This will return a coordinate that can be used for the location of the marker.

If you don't have the geographic bounds of these features, one option would be to use the [Mapbox Tilequery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/) to query for all building features within a particular radius, and then create a `LatLngBounds` object containing these buildings to use as the `Polygon` defining the boundaries of the block.